# How to fix "page trying to load scripts from unauthenticated source"

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, html

How can I fix this in my PHP page that contains ad scripts?

I have added scripts. It worked fine in HTTP but after I switched my site to HTTPS, nothing is appearing.

This is the error in dev console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   index.php:1
>
> Mixed Content: The page at `'https://myrevenuebank.com/index.php'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script `'http://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js'`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infolinks_pid = 2735394;
  var infolinks_wsid = 0;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can we have the link to the webpage? Do you know which script is causing the error?

Comment: all pages that contain the amazon ads and infolinks ad

Comment: ... and maybe some code.

Comment: https://www.myrevenuebank.com

Comment: i have already stated the script code of ad in the question plese help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

click View > Developer > JavaScript Console. 
Send us what errors you have in developer Console.
try to use https rather than http in script link.
also you can try to download the script and put it in your server.

1. you have 404 on menu.css (missing file)
2. you are loading http script from https website.
   change http://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js
   to https://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js

Comment: Have you corrected the https in the script? check also the menu.css file

Comment: you have also other problems: 
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/myrevenu/public_html/index.php on line 9 
This is probably the mysql driver.
if you don't mind - just lower the error reporting in php

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because browsers will block insecure content when accessing a secure page unless the user specifically allows that content.

You are trying to access `http://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js` from a secure connection, but that will not work. Instead change the URL to `//resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js` without the protocol.

Note: This will only work for things that can be accessed using exactly the same URL with both `http` and `https`, which is the case here. If the script is only available over `http`, you will not be able to access it via `https` and you would have to save it on your server instead of loading it from a remote server.